# How to index keywords using couchdb-lucene

Tags: couchdb

I'm trying to build a couchdb view using couchdb-lucene to query on keywords. I want lucene to index them without any processing.

I'm using `"index": "not_analyzed"` option, but it is still not doing as I expected.

When I query of `/works/OL1000010W`, couchdb-lucene is converting it into lowercase and stripping the first `/` character.

```
$ curl -s 'http://127.0.0.1:5984/editions_1k/_fti/_design/seeds/by_seed?q=seed:/works/OL1000010W&limit=1'
{
    "rows": [], 
    "total_rows": 0, 
    "skip": 0, 
    "search_duration": 1, 
    "q": "seed:works/ol1000010w", 
    "fetch_duration": 0, 
    "etag": "11e4be5bdb5c1598", 
    "limit": 1
}
```

Is there any way to make couchdb-lucene index it without processing and stop couchdb-lucene from processing the query?

Here is my design document: 
https://gist.github.com/670374

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found that this is due a bug in couchdb-lucene.

https://github.com/rnewson/couchdb-lucene/issues/#issue/92

And workaround is to write the view like this:

```
{
    "analyzer": "keyword",
    "index": "function(doc) {...}"
}
```